# Update/Add attribute to json array in T-SQL

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

All of the [examples](https://bertwagner.com/2017/03/07/the-ultimate-sql-server-json-cheat-sheet/) [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) I see dealing with json arrays have the array nested under a top level object. I have a json array in a column:
`[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]`

I would like to run a sql script to add/update a key for each element in the array, resulting in:
`[{"key": "value1", "otherKey": "otherValue"}, {"key": "value", "otherKey": "otherValue"}]`

Yes, in my case I want the same value set for each array member. I've tried:

```
declare @info nvarchar(max)
SET @info  = '[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]'
print JSON_MODIFY(@info, '[0].otherKey', '""')
```

and fails with "JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '[' is found at position 0."

This is in MSSQL 2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach, that can be used, depends on JSON structure (I assume, that the count of the items in the JSON array is not fixed):

- If the input JSON array has items (JSON objects) with fixed key/keys, you may use a combination of `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (to parse this JSON as table) and `FOR JSON` (to modify and return the rows as JSON)
- If the input JSON has items with different structure, you may use a combination of `OPENJSON()` with default schema, `JSON_MODIFY()` and `STRING_AGG()`.

JSON:

```
declare @info nvarchar(max)
SET @info  = '[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]'
```

Statement for fixed structure:

```
SELECT @info = (
   SELECT [key], 'OtherValue' AS OtherKey
   FROM OPENJSON(@info) WITH ([key] varchar(100) '$.key')
   FOR JSON PATH
)
```

Statement for variable structure:

```
SELECT @info = CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.OtherKey', 'OtherValue'), ','), ']')
FROM OPENJSON(@info)
SELECT @info
```

Result:

```
[{"key":"value1","OtherKey":"OtherValue"},{"key":"value2","OtherKey":"OtherValue"}]
```

Note, that the reason for the error is that the value of `path` parameter (`[0].otherKey`) is wrong. The correct path expression is `$[0].otherKey` for the first item in the JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `$` before the indexer sign?  Like:

```
declare @info nvarchar(max)
SET @info  = '[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]'
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$[0].otherKey', '""')
```

This gives the following output:

```
[{"key": "value1","otherKey":"\"\""}, {"key": "value2"}]
```